# SQL - Days Between Inbound and Outbound action in days

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

Attempting to write a query that returns how many days there are between an inbound action and an outbound action in our claims system, the bit I'm finding tricky is that they aren't always in the order you'd expect - so you'd expect an inbound communication is followed by an outbound, however it could be email in, email in then email out.. and it's just the last email action I need. So some example data would be

```
SELECT 1 AS RowNo
        , '123456' AS AccountNumber
        , 'IE' AS ActionType
        , 'Incoming Email' AS ActionDesc
        , '2022-05-03 09:19:33.000' AS DateTimeRecevied
        , '' AS DaysToReply
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS RowNo
        ,'123456' AS AccountNumber
        , 'IE' AS ActionType
        , 'Incoming Email' AS ActionDesc
        , '2022-05-21 10:07:22.000' AS DateTimeRecevied
        , '' AS DaysToReply
UNION ALL
SELECT 3 AS RowNo
        , '123456' AS AccountNumber
        , 'SE' AS ActionType
        , 'Send Email' AS ActionDesc
        , '2022-05-22 10:13:08.000' AS DateTimeRecevied
        , '1' AS DaysToReply
UNION ALL
SELECT 4 AS RowNo
        , '123456' AS AccountNumber
        , 'IE' AS ActionType
        , 'Incoming Email' AS ActionDesc
        , '2022-06-22 14:01:54.000' AS DateTimeRecevied
        , '' AS DaysToReply
```

so to explain as simply as possible I only want a result returned where there is a corresponding email out to an email in - so if there is NO email out after an email IN it returns nothing...

Days to reply is the desired output...

I've looked at some CTE variations but it never returns the desired result. Let me know if I'm not being clear..

Comment: So, for the above, what are you looking for? What are your expected results? You have 2 in's, followed by an out, followed by an in. Do you therefore want -28~ hours?

Comment: i'm looking for a calculation that would show the number of days between an email in and then the corresponding email out ignoring results where there was no email out following an email in....

Comment: So, you want `18` and `0`..? Please be explicit, rather than making us guess.

Comment: update the question now to explain and show as simply as possible..

Comment: I don't see any expected results in your question though...

Comment: refresh the query....its "Days to Reply"

Comment: Hiding your expected results in your sample data makes it easily missable.

Comment: And you have 2 sent emails in a row? What would be the results then? More than a single example would help here.

Comment: I've highlighted where I've put that in the query to make it clear for you...

Answer (score 1):

*Assuming* that an outbound email is always preceded by an inbound email (as your example has that logic, and you only state that there can be multiple ins in your wording, and [no clarification was given when this was asked about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72936532/sql-days-between-inbound-and-outbound-action-in-days#comment128824412_72936532)), then a `CASE` with `LAG` seems to work:

```sql
SELECT RowNo,
       ActionType,
       ActionDesc,
       DateTimeRecevied,
       DATEDIFF(DAY, CASE ActionDesc WHEN 'Send Email' THEN LAG(DateTimeRecevied) OVER (PARTITION BY AccountNumber ORDER BY RowNo) END,DateTimeRecevied) AS DaysToReply
FROM YourTable;
```

Comment: you'll find that in my original post that you edited i advised that there can be multiple emails in and that I am only interested in the latest email in which has a following out. I find you rude and offensive

Comment: The only edit I made was to remove the bold markdown, @XDSA5286 ... I haven't removed any content. I'm not sure what is rude or "offensive" about my answer, but if you truly believe that, then there is a "rude or abusive" flag option. I'm, however, really not sure how asking for clarification and providing an answer is "rude and offensive"; I would suggest that it's the opposite; I'm using my free time to try and get understanding on the problem from you, and giving you *free help*...